# how to control the video player size in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, css

i am looking for a way to set a specific size for the video player in WordPress     posts. i am using the WordPress built-in player and the J-W-player.
every player have a different size and i want to set a specific size for the players (like something general in style).
thank you.

Comment: did you check your player's stylesheet?, try to find the player div `class` and then you must find a `width` set in there, change it to the one you want.
In other case you name your own class and use your own style

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the markup and the class/id names of the players, you can use a single line of CSS to control the size:

```
    .jwplayer, .class_of_another_player, video {width:800px!important;}
```